# Take screenshot right before Windows locks

Tags: c#, windows, screenshot, lockscreen

I'm just playing around a bit. I try to take a screenshot of the main monitor right before the user locks the machine. So far nothing worked.

I tried a `SystemEvents.SessionSwith` but the window handler is not valid anymore at that time.

I also tried a `LowLevelKeyboardProc` to catch Win+L, take the screenshot and then lock the machine myself - but Win+L seems to be a somehow protected shortcut.

This is what I've got so far

```cs
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnStartup(e);
    SystemEvents.SessionSwitch += SystemEvents_SessionSwitch;
}

private void SystemEvents_SessionSwitch(object sender, SessionSwitchEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.Reason)
    {
        case SessionSwitchReason.SessionLock: TakeScreenShot(); break;
    }
}

private void TakeScreenShot()
{
    var screen = Screen.AllScreens.Single(x => x.Primary);
    var screenshot = new Bitmap(screen.Bounds.Width, screen.Bounds.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
    var gfxScreenshot = Graphics.FromImage(screenshot);
    gfxScreenshot.CopyFromScreen(screen.Bounds.X, screen.Bounds.Y, 0, 0, screen.Bounds.Size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);
    screenshot.Save("tmp.png");
}
```

Fails with `System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: 'The handle is invalid'`

Comment: Well this doesn't sound like a horrible security risk at all, no, not one bit!

Comment: So it's *not* the same as any other time. It's a time where the user has *explicitly* asked that the desktop should be *locked*. That's a security OS level event, not a dekstop or application UI event. `SessionSwitch` exists to warn applications that this change happened so they'll know that resources like the desktop is no longer available and that they'll probably have to take action to store their state.

Comment: `Screen.AllScreens.Single(x => x.Primary)` tries to work with the user's desktop, which is *no longer available*. Each user has a different desktop. The lock screen is a desktop that doesn't belong to any user. Trying to access the screen after locking fails because the desktop no longer exists.

Comment: I know. It would need some hook *before* the desktop is locked. Any creative ideas? And for the security concerns: Relax, it's just a fun project I spend less than an hour freetime on to see whats possible. Got inspired by a Linux lock-screen that shows a very pixelated version of the desktop.

Comment: `take the screenshot and then lock the machine myself ` is a **huge** security risk. If intercepting logout/locking was possible any malware would be able to fake logouts or locking and allow someone to use someone else's computer after they log out. That's possibly the oldest hack in the book, going back to fake login screens in the first UNIX computers. That's why non-interceptable keystrokes like `Ctrl+Alt+Del` and entirely different desktops are used for the lock screens *and* the UAE screen

Comment: Unix lock screens are rather notorious for being less than secure, incidentally, at least when you're talking classic X Windows. The various holes that have cropped up over the years that are a result of different processes having to talk to each other (some running privileged, others not) and window managers being left to do their own thing is exactly what Windows avoids with the dedicated desktop session for security stuff, and refusing to allow user apps to hook security. In the end, not being able to generate a cute pixelated desktop screenshot may be a small price to pay.

Comment: This is likely to only come to a good end when you lock the workstation yourself.  So you're always early enough.  https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.lockworkstation

Comment: The existence of a `SessionEnding` event to go with `SessionEnded` and `DisplaySettingsChanging` and `UserPreferenceChanging` made me hope someone had found a work around for the obvious lack of `SessionSwitching`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using my own shortcut (`Win+Shift+L`) for taking the screenshot and then locking the machine. Thanks @Hans Passant for the hint.